SessionID from tomcat is replaced but timeout not restarting?
I have a formcontrol for logging into my application. It works fine.
<form name="login" method ="POST" role="form" action="j_security_check">
      <div class="login">
         <label> Username</label>
         <input formControlName="username"  name="j_username" autofocus required>
      </div>

      <div class="login">
         <label> Password</label>
         <input type="password" formControlName="password"  name="j_password" required>
      </div>
     <button class="submit" type="submit"> Sing In</button>
</form>

In my application, I have a button that calls "logoutUser" which "invalidates" the session and takes me to the main page.
protected logoutUser() {
   this.http.post('/foo/logout', {}).subscribe ({
     next: () => {
        location.reload(); //reloads the page after the post call invalidates the session
     }});}

The tomcat's xml.config has a default 30 minute timeout and I noticed that the login page's session times out after 30 minutes and when i try to login again, i get the 408 Timeout from the j_security_check POST call.
I checked the Networking and I do see the sessionID changes everytime I login/logout. Is there a way to "keep alive" the login page past the timeout of 30 minutes? Because I need to clear the cache every time to remove the 30minute timeout.
I tried to reload the page using location.reload(true) but that doesn't work.
Any recommendations? thanks

This is a known behaviour. One solution would be to provide another login entry-point which stores credentials to the session and automatically re-submits the same user credentials once a protected resource is accessed. This should by-pass the j_security_check successfully. Checkout this source for a detailed solution : https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/j-security-check-login-tomcat-and-408-timed-out-request-8007

You can choose to increase the time-limit but that doesn't really solve the problem at hand.
